# Google calendar API service account rate limit

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a google service account setup for their calendar api, but it seems as though I can only make 5 requests per second. I've only figured that out from trial and error, there are no per second rate limit settings on my developer console settings.

I have 'queries per day' and 'queries per 100 seconds per user', both of which are currently set to 1,000,000.

I'm definitely not hitting these limits, so I can only assume there is a hidden 'per second' rate limit that is being applied. Does anyone know if that is the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en) will help you to understand more the Calendar usage limits.

Google Calendar puts certain limits in place to protect our users and infrastructure from abusive behavior. When these limits are reached by a user, Google Calendar will go into read-only mode for that user, and all edit actions will fail for a certain period of time. Most users will never hit these limits, as they are well above the activity level of a typical Calendar user.

I'd also like to add a few tips to work efficiently with your quota:

- Use [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push?utm_campaign=cal-10x-1214&utm_source=gadbc&utm_medium=blog) instead of polling.
- If you cannot avoid polling, make sure you only poll when necessary (for example poll very seldomly at night).
- Use [incremental synchronization](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) with sync tokens for all collections instead of repeatedly retrieving all the entries.
- Increase [page size](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/pagination) to retrieve more data at once by using the maxResults parameter.
- Update events when they change, avoid re-creating all the events on every sync.
- Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#exponential-backoff) for error retries.
- Check the [performance tips](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/performance) of the Calendar API